# How to customize recents screen for my android app?

Tags: android, android-recents, recent-screens

FYI, I'm new to android app development. This is my first app attempt.

I've setup my android app to run in landscape mode.  When I minimize the app, the image on the screen turns to portrait mode, and as a result, the image gets clipped at the bottom and looks bad.  See video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck0oRAG-k8o

How do I fix this so that I don't see this poorly formatted image when my app is minimized?  Is it possible to replace the image with something different?

Comment: Hi did you check in different device as it can be an issue of device launcher.

Comment: I checked in a virtual and physical device, and both give me this clipped result